# ASP.NET Core 8.0 no process information when publishing to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, .net-8.0

I want to get specific processes with a certain title (MainWindowTitle). Debugging this locally in Visual Studio works without any problems. But when I publish the application to IIS (locally) it still finds the same amount of processes but the "MainWindowTitle and MainWindowHandle" ared always empty (ProcessName is filled however).

Code I tried in a test project:

```
    public List<Process> GetProcesses()
    {
        List<Process> processes = [];

        var allProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();

        _logger.LogInformation($"All processes: {allProcesses.Count()}");

        foreach (var process in allProcesses)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Process name: {process.ProcessName}. Title: {process.MainWindowTitle}");

            nint mainWindowHandle = process.MainWindowHandle;


            if (mainWindowHandle != nint.Zero)
            {
                processes.Add(process);
            }
        }

        _logger.LogInformation($"Processes: {processes.Count()}");

        return processes;
    }
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\ProcessesWebApplication.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
    <system.web>
        <identity impersonate="true" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

- Tried to publish it to different locations (wwwroot and outside)
- Created new Application pool/site, tried multiple identity (ApplicationPoolIdentity, LocalSystem)  - Load User Profile on/off

It seems to be something with access/security. But how can/should I fix this? Running the application directly from command line also works without any problems: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ProcessesWebAplication>dotnet ProcessesWebApplication.dll

**Edit:**

I tried multiple Identity users for the application pool and logged the result using this code:

```
WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
_logger.LogInformation($"Identity: {principal.Identity}. Name: {identity.Name}. Owner: {identity.Owner}. AuthenticationType: {identity.AuthenticationType}. IsAnonymous: {identity.IsAnonymous}. IsAuthenticated: {identity.IsAuthenticated}. ");
```

*Identity LocalSystem:*

Identity: System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity. Name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. Owner: S-xxx. AuthenticationType: NTLM. IsAnonymous: False. IsAuthenticated: True.

*Identity ApplicationPoolIdentity:*

Identity: System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity. Name: IIS APPPOOL\ProcessesWebAplication. Owner: S-xxx. AuthenticationType: Negotiate. IsAnonymous: False. IsAuthenticated: True.

*Custom account (this is exactly the same as debugging in Visual Studio, but it's still not returning the full process info):*

Identity: System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity. Name: xxx\xxx. Owner: S-xxx. AuthenticationType: CloudAP. IsAnonymous: False. IsAuthenticated: True.

ManagementObjectSearcher does seem to work when published to IIS, but does not return the MainWindowHandle I need to send a command to.

Comment: Well, It seems your code itself is syntactically correct, the issue might be  lies in the IIS execution context and its security restrictions. So what's your `SeDebugPrivilege` status?  You can try with [`ManagementObjectSearcher` instead. Please check this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobjectsearcher?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0)

Comment: Yes it seems to be something with the IIS execution context. I tried to enable SeDebugPrivilege but it does not seem to help. I've edited the post above with different identities I tried and the findings of using ManagementObjectSearcher (works, but does not provide the info I need).

Answer (score 0):

First of all have look at the following screenshot, which showing the windowTitle of the current process title name.

[image]

I have used following code to achieve above output:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int processId);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc callback, IntPtr lParam);

delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam);

public Process[] GetProcessesWithWindowNames()
{
    var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
    var processWindowNames = new Dictionary<Process, string>();

   
    EnumWindows(delegate (IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        int processId;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out processId);
        Process process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);

       
        if (!processWindowNames.ContainsKey(process))
        {
            StringBuilder windowText = new StringBuilder(256);
            GetWindowText(hWnd, windowText, windowText.Capacity);

            if (windowText.Length > 0)
            {
                processWindowNames.Add(process, windowText.ToString());
            }
        }

        return true;
    }, IntPtr.Zero);

    return processWindowNames.Keys.ToArray();
}
```

Now back to your question which is as following:

> When I publish the application to IIS (locally) it still finds the
> same amount of processes but the "MainWindowTitle and
> MainWindowHandle" ared always empty (ProcessName is filled however).

As I said earlier, it might have permission issues. But [most importantly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle?view=net-8.0#remarks),this might not work,  if you are trying to access the `MainWindowTitle` property for a process that is running on a remote computer. Because this property is available only for processes that are running on the local computer.

Even, if the process doesn't contains any GUI interface, that also may not get any MainWindowTitle property.

**Note:** Please [refer this official documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle?view=net-8.0#exceptions) which has clarified that `MainWindowTitle` might may be empty or get exception while running to remote server or the process that doesn't have GUI. So we are getting empty value.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. It's running on a local computer as a ASP.NET Core 8.0 (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web) application (similar as your example/screenshot).

Any chance that you can publish the application to IIS and see if it works for you? (should have the same issue then I guess)

Comment: Yes, I have also tried that and the behavior is same without any GUI it cannot fetch the `MainWindowTitle`, then I check with document I shared with you.

Comment: Do you mean it's not working for you when published to IIS? Because in your screenshot it's working while debugging (same for me). I don't get the MainWindowTitle for any of the processes running when published to IIS. Not just processes without any GUI. So it seems more like a security thing to me, but I tried running the Application Pool under different users (also the same as the processes are running), but that doesn't help unfortunately

Comment: Yeah you are right, its not working for me in IIS either. Based on the document it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for trying out/confirming. Any idea how this can be done in another way?

Comment: You cannot get the `MainWindowTitle` title from IIS server specially while publish your application in windows server, its not allowed.